# Menu built with JS don't work on the latest Chrome version

Tags: javascript

I have to find a problem in [an old file](http://www.theatre.lv/menu-tests.html) with the menu which works in Chrome only if I change user agent to Firefox. Then in the Inspect Tools it shows such error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Property 'awmwbl' of object is not a function

and the code in that place looks like this:

```
function awmwbl() {}

function awmwl() {
    if (!(navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Konqueror') > -1)) awmwbl();
    for (var mno = 0; mno < awmm.length; mno++) {
        if (!awmm[mno].cll) awmm[mno].cn[0].pc();
    }
}
```

I'm wondering could this be the reason why the file is not working on the latest Chrome? Because the file was working for many years till the last month.

Here is html code:

```
<BODY>
<!-- ******** BEGIN ALLWEBMENUS CODE FOR menu ******** --> 
<script >var MenuLinkedBy='AllWebMenus [1]', awmBN='DW'; awmAltUrl='';</script> 
<script charset='UTF-8' src='menu.js.php'></script> 
<script >awmBuildMenu();</script> 
<!-- ******** END ALLWEBMENUS CODE FOR menu ******** -->

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
<span id='awmAnchor-menu'>&nbsp;</span>
      </table></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</BODY>
```

Comment: Can we see a live example?

Comment: Why are you working with minified code?

Comment: @cookiemonster: It looks like the menu code was written by someone else.

Comment: Example is here - http://www.theatre.lv/menu-tests.html . I won't be able to put it in jsfiddle since it has several large js files attached. I just wonder is there any obvious problems.

Comment: yes the code is bought as a plugin very long time ago. I am not a developer, I just tried to see if there any obvious problems.

Comment: @Robert002: Which line is that error occurring on?  Have you tried to debug this yourself?

Comment: its not event working in firefox.

Comment: @Zaheer Ahmed - yes - probably in all latest versions it doesn't work. On my computer I use opera 16 - and it works and in chrome it works if   user agent is switched to firefox15

Answer (score 1):

First I'd fill in that function with some kind of statement. Empty functions might act weird (just a guess). If that doesn't work, I'd try assigning it to a variable, like;

`var awmwbl = function() { console.log('it's working');}`

But I have a feeling the problem is not in he code you provide, but inside some conditional that's checking for a particular browser.

Comment: I tried to change that function, the error disappear, but the menu is still hidden in the latest browsers, so probably you are right that the problem is somewhere else